# convert array of objects to a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I convert the following array of objects to a javascript string:

```
"contacts": [{"contactName": "ABC XYZ", "contactDesgn": "Associate Director", "contactPhone": "9892265172", "contactEmail": "ABC.XYZ@test.com", "level": "L4"}]
```

I want the resulting string to be like this:

```
<#>ABC XYZ<#>Associate Director<#>9892265172<#>ABC.XYZ@test.com<#>L4<$>
```

Comment: expected result: <#>ABC XYZ<#>Associate Director<#>9892265172<#>ABC.XYZ@test.com<#>L4<$>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let contact = [{"contactName": "ABC XYZ", "contactDesgn": "Associate Director", "contactPhone": "9892265172", "contactEmail": "ABC.XYZ@test.com", "level": "L4"}];

let result = contact[0];

let string = `<#>${result.contactName}<#>${result.conatactDesign}<#>${result.contactPhone}<#>${result.contactEmail}<#>${result.level}<$>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values()` to get an array of values from your JSON. Use `Array.join` to chain the values by `<#>` and finally concatenate the leading and trailing tags.

```js
contacts = [{"contactName": "ABC XYZ", "contactDesgn": "Associate Director", "contactPhone": "9892265172", "contactEmail": "ABC.XYZ@test.com", "level": "L4"}];
console.log ('<#>' + Object.values (contacts[0]).join ('<#>') + '<$>');
```